# How can I programmatically catch all the errors in an interface class library

Tags: c#, interface, exception

like maybe IExceptionWrapper.

How do we make an exception catcher like onError that we can apply to every class in the class library? without writing try-cach again and again...

Comment: no one to answer?

Comment: I have no idea?